# Using the output of a partial as a variable in main template

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

Out of this question: [Random image with v:iterator.random | cache issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597141/random-image-with-viterator-random-cache-issue/36600054#36600054)

I use a partial to render non-cacheable stuff (in this case a random image).
I do this with this code in the main-template:

```
{v:render.uncache(partial: 'Random-Image',  arguments: {iterator: images})}
```

Have this directly in the template outputs the right thing (the url to an image, for example `fileadmin/upload/abc.jpg`). But if I want to use this as a variable for the src from `<f:image` it does not work:

```
<f:image src="{v:render.uncache(partial: 'Random-Image',  arguments: {iterator: images})}" alt="alt text" />
```

Also set as a variable it with `v:variable.set` does not work.

All I get is: `<!--INT_SCRIPT.0081e57d9fd92c925bb35d79fd9d3f79-->`

Also when I debug it:

```
<f:debug>
{v:render.uncache(partial: 'Random-Image',  arguments: {iterator: images})}
</f:debug>
```

I get `<!--INT_SCRIPT.0081e57d9fd92c925bb35d79fd9d3f79-->`

So, is it possible to use the output of a partial as a variable? Or is it possible to set a variable in the partial and use it in the main-template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up two things a bit, so I would like to separate your questions:

**1) Is it possible to use the output of a partial as a variable?**

Yes, like the way you wanted it. Actually you did it.

But let see a test:

There is a Partial : Test/Message
With the content: "It is a test"

Then in the main template you can use something like this:

```
    <div class="test">
       <f:if condition="{f:render(partial:'Test/Message')}
             == 'It is a test'">
          <f:then>Passed</f:then>
          <f:else>Failed</f:else>
       </f:if>
    </div>
```

In this case you would see "Passed" and if you change the Partial to "It should failed" then you will get "Failed" rendered.

**2) Why do you see `<!--INT_SCRIPT.0081e57d9fd92c925bb35d79fd9d3f79-->` ?**

This is a not cached content, so like `COA_INT` or `USR_INT` objects in `TypoScript`.

You can find a function in the `typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php` its name is `INTincScript_process`. It is responsible to find such lines in the code and replace them with the not cached content.

It means, if you render your Template, that partial renders only a reference to a not cached object, but not the content itself.

Finally to suggest a solution to the original problem, try to render the whole image inside the partial not just the path to it. So include the  into the partial where the v:iterate.random ViewHelper is used. Then the v:render.uncache should mark the whole image block as not cacheable.

Comment: Ah.. so maybe my question was a bit wrong. to your **2)** part: would it be possible to use this  (the output of `{v:render.uncache`) as a variable? What I wanted is to just select 1 random iterator item and use this in the main template (that is cached)

Comment: Also would you take a look at my original question? Maybe there is a much better way to do what I want without a partial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597141/random-image-with-viterator-random-cache-issue/36600054#36600054

Comment: I think, you can not achieve that. You can not return the the result of the partial as a string or a variable with the v:render.uncache, because the ViewHelper generates a non cacheable content and delivers only the pointer to it.

Comment: I think you should use the <f:image> part of your question inside the Partial, so try to deliver the whole image with it, not just the path to it, and ignore the INT_SCRIPT it is only to get the content not cached.

Comment: I understand, thanks, very interesting. To you second comment, yes thats what I do right now, I use the f:image inside the partial. My goal was to create a universal partial that I can also use for other iterators. I dislike the fact that I need a separate file just for this small task